# Is iptables able to filter off UNREPLIED connections?

Tags: iptables

I am a using `dd-wrt` router and trying to get some per-user metrics, I was wondering about filtering only `ESTABLISHED` connections or include `NEW` and `RELATED`, I have read a lot about this last two, but I am still not sure about considering it part of used bandwidth...

Well, first check the following script: http://pastebin.com/TERtu4hT

Let us say I am not excluding any `state`, I want to get all of them, what happened is:

1. We have UPnP activated;
2. Skype uses UPnP;
3. This machine opened TCP and UDP ports for Skype over UPnP;
4. The machine is now offline;
5. There is still requests from remote users to connect to this machine over UDP port;
6. Sometimes I receive `NEW` state connections, which `conntrack` says is `UNREPLIED`, but `iptabless` still consider its bandwidth;
7. All other states: `ESTABLISHED`, `RELATED`, `INVALID` and `UNTRACKED`, remains zero or unchanged;

The result could be seen here: http://pastebin.com/0vS0jLwv

What should I do? Considering only `ESTABLISHED` connections would solve, but is it the correct metrics? Or there is any way to `iptables` ignore `UNREPLIED` packages?